# SQL SELECT INSERTed data from Table

Tags: sql, select, asp-classic, insert

its in ASP Classic. MS-Access DB.

i do: `INSERT INTO Orders (userId) VALUES (123)"`

what i want to retrieve is `orderNumber` from that row. its an auto-increment number.

so i did: `SELECT orderNumber FROM Orders WHERE userId=123`

but since it is on the same page, the SELECT returns: **Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.**

i've seen somewhere `RETURNING orderNumber as variable` but it was for oracle and i dont know how to implement it into my asp :(

```
set addOrder = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        addOrder.ActiveConnection = MM_KerenDB_STRING
        addOrder.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Orders (userId) VALUES ("&userId&")"
        addOrder.CommandType = 1
        addOrder.CommandTimeout = 0
        addOrder.Prepared = true
        addOrder.Execute()

Dim getOrderNumber
Set getOrderNumber = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        getOrderNumber.ActiveConnection = MM_KerenDB_STRING
        getOrderNumber.Source = "SELECT orderNumber FROM Orders WHERE userId=" & userId
        getOrderNumber.CursorType = 0
        getOrderNumber.CursorLocation = 2
        getOrderNumber.LockType = 1
        getOrderNumber.Open()

                    session("orderNumber") = getOrderNumber.Fields.Item("orderNumber").value
```

Comment: Can we see some of the ASP code you use to actually run the SQL statement?

Comment: sorry, i was assuming (WRONG) that it was irrelevant

Comment: Does the first statement actually enter data into your table? I want to make sure that it isn't a problem with the first statement. So when you run the page and get the error is there data in your access database?

Comment: You really should be using parameterized queries instead of assembling your SQL statement via concatenation. I.e., your SQL statement should look like: `Insert Into Orders(userid) Values(@UserId)`. What database system are you using?

Comment: @Thomas i use MS-Access, with ASP-Classic. i tried changing my concatenation to @var but it failed. i'll just point that my variable come from the ASP, not SQL..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might be of help if you are using their method of adding records using ADO objects.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/221931

But without actually seeing you Classic ASP code, it is hard to give you a proper answer.

Comment: for some strange reason my code looks completly different from the you pointed in the link.. :/ i feel dumb.. thats what maccromedia gave me.. can i do better? :)

Comment: @Noam There are multiple ways to work with data in Classic ASP. You can either use ADODB.Command objects to insert/delete/update/select records or you can do the same with ADODB.RecordSet objects. Macromedia seems to use commands for inserting and recordsets for selecting. Note that when you use commands to select you are still getting recordsets back.

Comment: i did what was in your link and it worked :) since i always hated macromedia doing it for me, i think its time i really get more into understanding what that code actually does. can u point me where i can read about it? and the differences between command and recordset..

Comment: @Noam w3schools.com has some nice stuff on ADO in addition to pages on each of the ADO objects and all the properties and methods that they contain. http://www.w3schools.com/ado/default.asp